# Jenkins Workspace getting deleted

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins deleted the workspace every time the build job is run. I am using the latest version for SCM plugin. 
I do not want the workspace to be created every time. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your checkout strategy under SCM plugin to emulate clean workspace?

Comment: Check-out Strategy : "Use SVN Updates as much as possible". I am using Subversion plugin-in 2.4

Comment: Please paste your full console log into the original question, or at least everything up to the build steps